# Sub-select in select clause and using with its value

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a way to return the sub-select and return manipulate that depend on this field ?

For example, can I do something like this:

```
select a, (select top 1 b from b) as b, (a * b) as c
from a
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a, b, (a * b) as c
from (
    select a, (select top 1 b from b) as b
    from a
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select a.a, b.b, (a.a * b.b) as c
from a cross join
     (select top 1 b from b) b;
```